# Jquery attr or prop?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

i some have custom property from code behind.

i add them using

```
 sender.Attributes.Add("TextLinkNo", sender.TextLinkNo)
        sender.Attributes.Add("TextHeader", sender.TextHeader)
        sender.Attributes.Add("TextDisplay", sender.TextDisplay)
        sender.Attributes.Add("FSize", sender.FSize)
        sender.Attributes.Add("iRotation", sender.iRotation)
        sender.Attributes.Add("PrintStatus", sender.PrintStatus)
        sender.Attributes.Add("Parameter", sender.Parameter)
        sender.Attributes.Add("SupportDEC", sender.SupportDEC)
```

html code

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelAttributes1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_08" 
itextstyle="0" asign="0" supportdec="0" linetp="0" textlinkno="0" parameter="0" 
supportfontsize="False" class="draglabel ui-draggable ui-resizable" printstatus="7" 
spaceadjust="0" irotation="0" actc5="False" index="8" fieldformat="C1" ifontstyle="0" 
stringstatus="0" fsize="-1" ialign="0" textdisplay="Commodity Name" textheader="False" 
istartline="0" style="position: absolute; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; left: 9px; top: 205px; width: 476px; height: 174px; background-color: rgb(255, 192, 203);" top="8" left="19">
Commodity Name
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div></span>
```

i can get these properties using

```
$(this).attr("supportdec");
```

but not

```
$(this).prop("supportdec");
$(this).prop("data-supportdec");
```

i tot prop is supported what attr supported +additional?

Comment: so why cant you just use attr?

Comment: i just want to know why prop not able to get the value. i use whatever it works. is just a general question.some said attr get something close but not actual value. prop is better over attr. but i find that prop always not able to get what i want

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/543693) I believe it explains what you're asking in detail. From that answer: "An attribute value may only be a string whereas a property can be of any type. For example, the checked property is a Boolean, the style property is an object with individual properties for each style, the size property is a number."

Comment: hi adam
i read that artical too. but everywhere is using checked as example.
so am i right to say that. for checked property. we use prop is better. and the rest use attr?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 2):

There have been numerous questions already asked which document the difference between `.attr()` and `.prop()`.

I would recommend reading through this [StackOverlfow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

The difference is also documented in the `jQuery` api for the `.prop()` function, which is [located here.](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

The following was pulled from the jQuery site mentioned above.

> Attributes vs. Properties
>
> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.
>
> For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved
>   and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery
>   1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr. These do not have corresponding
>   attributes and are only properties.
>
> According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a
>   boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if
>   the attribute is present at all—even if, for example, the attribute
>   has no value or is set to empty string value or even "false". This is
>   true of all boolean attributes.
>
> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked
>   attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The
>   attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and
>   should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The
>   checked attribute value does not change with the state of the
>   checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the
>   cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is
>   to use the property.